# how to dynamically assign column heading for rdlc report

Tags: sql-server, rdlc, rdl, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have a rdlc weekly report. The user can select `date from` and `date to`. Then the report will show the sales done on that week separated by hours.

eg:
let say user entered `06-Jun-2016` and `12-Jun-2016`. Then a sample report will be like below

```
Hours       Mon-20160606 Tue-20160607 ............. Sun-20160612
00-10         500          1000                       0
10-14         750          0                          0
```

I am able to generate the report but each time the user will change the date from and date to. According to that the column heading need to change.

If the second time user select the input as `19-Jun-2016` and `25-Jun-2016`
the report heading will be as below

```
Hours       Sun-20160619 Mon-20160620 ............. Sat-20160625
```

How can I achieve this.

**Procedure using for rdlc**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_hourly_data]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @start_date varchar(20), 
    @end_date varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN


if object_id('tempdb..#Timing', 'U') is not NULL
  exec('drop table #Timing')

if object_id('tempdb..#WeekDays', 'U') is not NULL
  exec('drop table #WeekDays')

declare
  @DateBegin    datetime = @start_date,
  @DateEnd      datetime = @end_date,
  @TradeDateEnd datetime


set @TradeDateEnd = dateadd(hour, 4, dateadd(day, 1, @DateEnd))

declare
  @sql                    nvarchar(max),
  @col_per_day_list       nvarchar(max),
  @pivot_val_per_day_list nvarchar(max),
  @sum_cols_per_day_list  nvarchar(max)



create table #Timing
(
  hrs smallint,
  hours_start smallint,
  hours_end   smallint,
  period varchar(11)
)

;with cteTiming as
(
  select 4 as hrs

  union all

  select t.hrs+1
  from cteTiming t
  where t.hrs < 27
)
insert into #Timing (hrs, hours_start, hours_end, period)
select t.hrs, hrs % 24, (hrs + 1) % 24, 
  cast(hrs % 24 as varchar(10)) + ':00-' + cast((hrs+1) % 24 as varchar(10)) + ':00'
from cteTiming t



create table #WeekDays
(
  wd smallint,
  wd_date datetime,
  wd_name varchar(12)
)

;with cteWeekDays as
(
  select
    datepart(weekday, @DateBegin) wd,
    cast(@DateBegin as date) wd_date

  union all

  select
    wd.wd+1,
    dateadd(day, 1, wd.wd_date) wd_date
  from cteWeekDays wd
  where wd_date < cast(@DateEnd as date)
)
insert into #WeekDays (wd, wd_date, wd_name)
select wd.wd, wd.wd_date,
  left(datename(weekday, wd.wd_date), 3) + '-' + convert(varchar(8), wd.wd_date, 112)
from cteWeekDays wd


select
  @sum_cols_per_day_list = stuff(wd.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
from
  (
    select
      ',
  Sum(IsNull(r.' + quotename(wd.wd_name) + ', 0)) as ' + quotename(wd.wd_name)
    from #WeekDays wd
    order by wd.wd_date
    for xml path(''), type
  ) x(wd)

select
  @col_per_day_list = stuff(wd.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
from
  (
    select
      ',
    p.' + quotename(wd.wd_name)
    from #WeekDays wd
    order by wd.wd_date
    for xml path(''), type
  ) x(wd)

set @pivot_val_per_day_list = replace(@col_per_day_list, 'p.[', '  [')


set @sql = cast(N'
;with cteSales as
(
  select
    datepart(weekday, s.start_date) as SalesWeekDay,
    datediff(hour, cast(s.start_date as date), s.start_date) DayTime,
    s.start_date SalesDate,
    s.sale_total OrigionalSubTotal
  from sale s
  where s.start_date >= @DateBegin and s.start_date < @DateEnd

),
cteSalesPerWeekDays as
(
  select
    p.hrs,
    p.period,' as nvarchar(max)) + @col_per_day_list + N'
  from #Timing t
  cross join #WeekDays w
  left join cteSales s on datediff(hour, w.wd_date, s.SalesDate) = t.hrs
  pivot
  (
    Sum(s.OrigionalSubTotal)
    for w.wd_name in (' + @pivot_val_per_day_list + N')
  ) p
)
select
  r.hrs,
  r.period as [From-To],' + @sum_cols_per_day_list + N'
from cteSalesPerWeekDays r
group by r.hrs, r.period
order by r.hrs
'

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@DateBegin datetime, @DateEnd datetime',
  @DateBegin = @DateBegin,
  @DateEnd = @TradeDateEnd


if object_id('tempdb..#Timing', 'U') is not NULL
  exec('drop table #Timing')

if object_id('tempdb..#WeekDays', 'U') is not NULL
  exec('drop table #WeekDays')
End
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen edited question with the procedure used for rdlc

Comment: you could drag the parameter into first column header and add day to the next column like DateAdd("d",1,Parameters!ftdt.Value) as on...

Comment: @nazark 'Mon-20160606' is not a date value to add day

Comment: but you could create date from it ie, right(Mon-20160606,8)

Comment: @nazark will it dynamically change tue,wed,thur....

Comment: @nazark yes always 7 days

Comment: example  in SSRS expression =DateAdd("d",1,CDate(right("Mon-20160606",2) & "/" &Mid("Mon-20160606",9,2)& "/" & Mid("Mon-20160606",5,4))) and format control as  'ddd yyyyMMdd' you will get the result